# Add text above and below an image in a pdf using itextsharp(asp.net,C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I have converted an image into `byte[]` using memorystream and then added the `byte[]` to a pdf using itextsharp.
Now my requirement is to add a certain text above the image which gives some information about the image.

this is my code

```
private void generatepdf(byte[] byteImage)
    {
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(byteImage);
    image.ScalePercent(0.3f * 100);
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 188f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
        document.Open();
        document.Add(image);
        document.Close();
        byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
    }
```

How can I add some text and convert into bytes and then send it through to the pdf object. Or is there any better way to guide me in correct direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this

```
        private void generatepdf(byte[] byteImage)
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(byteImage);
            image.ScalePercent(0.3f * 100);
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 188f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);

                string text1 = "before image";
                Paragraph text1Title = new Paragraph(text1);

                string text2 = "after image";
                Paragraph text2Title = new Paragraph(text2);

                document.Open();
                document.Add(text1Title);
                document.Add(image);
                document.Add(text2Title);
                document.Close();
                byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                memoryStream.Close();

                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks ,it worked, however, how can I set the position of that text/image in the pdf. I tried Image.SetAbsolutePostion(X,Y) for image, but in vain.

Comment: tell me what you want to do

Comment: I want to set the text at a particular position, i.e. (X,Y) coordinates in the pdf.